# How to detect moments of state change in boolean time series?

Tags: time-series, smoothing, change-point

Let $A = (X_1, ... X_n)$ be a series consisting of long periods of ones interrupted with shorter periods of zeros, like
$$A = 111111111 00000001111111111100000011111111111111.$$

The plot below (left) shows this kind of data but with larger number of points. Plot on the right shows the same data but the pattern is slightly disrupted (for example due to defect of device used to collect the data)

$$A_d = 11101111100000001111111011100001011111111111111.$$

[image]

Code used to generate the plotted data:

```
import numpy as np
lengths = [80, 40, 100, 40, 100]
data = np.array([])
for i,l in enumerate(lengths):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        data = np.append(data, np.array([1] * l))
    else:
        data = np.append(data, np.array([0] * l))

bad_ones = list(range(99,105)) + [115,117] + [230, 232, 250]
bad_zeros = [40,43, 300,301, 310]
data_with_errors = data.copy()
data_with_errors[bad_ones] = 1
data_with_errors[bad_zeros] = 0
```

My questions are:

1. Given a smooth pattern array `data` what is the most efficient way to detect times of change in state? In our example this algorithm should return array `[ 80 120 220 260]` (red points).
2. The same problem but for `data_with_errors` (for plot on the right should still return `[ 80 120 220 260]`).

My solution to problem 1 (I don't know if it can be optimized):

```
diffs = np.diff(data)
np.where(diffs != 0)[0] + 1 # plus 1 because we want to know the index of the first element of the new pattern not last of the current pattern
```

I don't know what to do about problem 2 - my guess is that I should somehow smooth the disrupted pattern first, but right now I don't know how to smooth this kind of data and even how to properly google it.

Comment: Re "most efficient way:" that depends on your assumptions about the statistical properties of the data; equivalently, on your model for the errors.  There are *loads* of plausible solutions.  In the examples you give, replacing the data with a windowed median for a window of size 5 or greater would do the trick, for instance.  If you could provide more relevant background information we might be able to help you find a good answer.